# How to count how many splits have been made

Tags: java, android

So here's my problem. I use this code and it doesn't work. I want to split string called response and get number of how many peaces it have been splited.

```
public void updateSQLite(String response){
        String[] kazkiek = response.split(";");
        System.out.println(response);
        for(int p = 0; p <= 2; p++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= kazkiek.length; i++) {}
        }
}
```

My Android Monitor returns this error :

> Unhandled exception origin cause
>                                                                                      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

As I saw on other questions it's because there is only one index. My String is a long one, and splitted into more than 300 peaces.

Comment: I don't think you posted the right code or relevant code. There is no indexing in the posted code, and the exception cannot possible come from here.

Comment: Amount of splits is equal to `kazkiek.length`.

Comment: @janos When I changed kazkiek.lenght to 20 for testing, everything was fine

Comment: Do you need to use two times for loop?

Comment: @MilosLulic Well yes, basically I coppied the code where the error happens

Comment: My suggestion is learn/understand how to use loop properly before trying split.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you use `for(int i=0;i<=thing.lenth;i++)` but here is working code

```
String tt = "asldkj;alskdjfh;alksdjfhlads;lkajsdfhlkas;lkajsdhflkadsf;lkjasdhflkjasdf;lkajsdhflkajshdf;lajkshdflkhasdf;alskdjflkajsdfölk;ölkajsdföljasdöfl;aölksdjfölkajsdf";
String[] test = tt.split(";");
int count =0;
for(int p = 0; p <= 2; p++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i+" "+test[i]);
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count+" peaces!");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your inner for loop is creating an out of bounds exception, because it is iterating more times than there are values in kazkiek (try `for (int i = 0; i < kazkiek.length; i++) {}`).

Here's some sample code:

```
private void splitString(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split(";");
    int wordCount = words.length;
    System.out.println("number of words: " + String.valueOf(wordCount));
    for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Comment: Actually his loop and yours are "fine", the error posted by the OP is not caused in the snippet he shows